# how to add the Filter option to Flutter APP

Tags: flutter

I am beginner to the flutter app development currently I am trying to add a filter option to my mobile app , which once clicked a popup should come like the below image, like in youtube once clicking on the 3 vertical dots on a vedio a popup is coming on the bottom, I want to do exactly like that but I am not getting how to do that, can anyone help me with this.

here is the popup,
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3XGF.png)

Comment: look at [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html)

Comment: Please use bottomsheet widget

Answer (score 0):

Use ModelBottomSheet

```
void _settingModalBottomSheet(context) {
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext bc) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text('text1'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.add_alarm),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('text2'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('text2'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

call _modalBottomSheetMenu method in onPressed